# Zod - Checking the number of digits on a number type

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm unable to figure out how to check for the number of digits in a number using Zod.

Since I'm converting my string value to a number, I'm unable to use min() or max() to check for the number of digits.

I've tried using lte() and gte() the following when building my schema:

```
export const MySchema = z.object({
  type1: z.coerce.string(),
  type2: z.coerce.string(),
  type4: z.coerce.number().lte(5).gte(5),
  type5: z.coerce.number()
})
```

My goal is to limit `type4` to a fix length of 5 digits for validation. What could be an alternative solution? Maybe checking the string length before converting to a number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the number must be an integer, this can be achieved with no special transforms or preprocesses:

```js
// Omitting the wrapper stuff
z.coerce.number() // Force it to be a number
  .int() // Make sure it's an integer
  .gte(10000) // Greater than or equal to the smallest 5 digit int
  .lte(99999) // Less than or equal to the largest 5 digit int
```

If the number can be a decimal, then the other answer to this question is probably your best bet.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me since I am working with integers only. However, Zoltán's solution would also work if I was using decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the transform method on the z.string() validator for type4. The transformer function checks that the length of the string is 5, and if it's not, it throws an error. If the length is 5, the function converts the string to a number using parseInt.

```
const MySchema = z.object({
  type1: z.string(),
  type2: z.string(),
  type4: z.string().transform((val) => {
    if (val.length !== 5) throw new Error('Type4 must have 5 digits')
    return parseInt(val, 10)
  }),
  type5: z.number()
})
```

Comment: Rather than throwing an error directly from the transform function, it's typically a bit better to use the second `ctx` argument to `transform` to `addIssue` so that if you parse this with `safeParse` the error is not thrown.

Comment: Another thing you could do is use `z.string().length(5)` along with `safeParse` in the transform function to reuse all of the nice error messages `zod` packs with it. For example if we stored the `safeParse` result as `result` then you could `ctx.addIssue(result.error.issues)` when `result.success` is `false`